# Invalid conversion from const &parameter to &parameter seems to be nonsense?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, function-pointers

I am just curious. I am passing pointer to function with signature

```
void printCommandReceived(const CommandDescriptor &descriptor)
```

as third parameter to constructor with signature

```
CommandLogFilter::CommandLogFilter(QSharedPointer<LogServer> logServer, QObject *parent,
                      void (*preprocessValidCommand)(CommandDescriptor &descriptor))
```

and getting error from g++ compiler:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(const CommandDescriptor&)’ to ‘void (*)(CommandDescriptor&)’ [-fpermissive]
```

In my understanding the reference to non-const object should be usable as argument to reference to const object parameter. So parameter with type pointer to function accepting non-const object reference should be more than satisfied with (and do implicit conversion from) argument of type pointer to function, which accepts even const object reference.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You have a "pointer to something" and want to pass a "pointer to something else". There is no implicit conversion in that case, even when the pointed-to types are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void (*)(const CommandDescriptor&)` and `void (*)(CommandDescriptor&)` are two completely different, unrelated types.

There are very simple rules regarding `const`: `X*` can be converted to  `X const*`, `X**` can be converted to `X const * const *` and so on. Same thing with references. Nothing else is allowed.

Note that the rules do not allow to arbitrarily add or remove `const` at any position in the type, for example, `X**` cannot be converted to `X const **`. This is true also for the position of function arguments: you just cannot add or remove `const` there to get a compatible type.

Could these rules be extended so that they accommodate cases like yours and remain consistent? Probably so. But they are not.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a limited set of situations where `const` can be added or removed implicitly.  You ran into one where it cannot be done.  The reason why not is probably as simple as "describing those cases which are safe would be hard, and standards writers are lazy and conservative".

As a work around, you can do this:

```
CommandLogFilter bob(
  logServer,
  parent,
  [](CommandDescriptor &descriptor) {
    return printCommandReceived(descriptor);
  }
);
```

as stateless lambdas can implicitly convert-to a pointer to a function matching their signature.

I don't like having to make the signature explicit there, but there is no way to do something similar with template "auto" lambdas and have the signature deduced unfortunately.